# How to clean up existing response in webapi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

There is a authentication library that I have to use that helpfully does things like

```
Response.Redirect(url, false);
```

inside of it's method calls. I can't change this libraries code and it's fine for MVC style apps but in angular SPA -> WebApi apps this is just awful.

I really need a 401 otherwise I get into trouble with CORS when my angular scripts, using $http, try to call out to the auth server on another domain in response to the 302, that's if it even could as the `Response.Redirect` also sends down the `object moved` html and the angle brackets cause an error to be thrown.

Since I have to make the call to the auth library first the `Response.Redirect` is already in the response pipeline and so I need to clean it up to remove the body content and convert the 302 into a 401. I thought I could just:

```
return new HttpWebResponse(StatusCode.UnAuthorized){
         Content = new StringContent("data");
}
```

but this just gets appended to the response and doesn't replace it plus I also need the Location: header which I can't seem to access via WebApi methods.

So instead I've had to do this in my ApiController:

```
var ctxw = this.Request.Properties["MS_HtpContext"] as HttpContextWrapper;
var ctx = ctxw.ApplicationInstance.Context;
var url = ctx.Response.RedirectLocation;
ctx.Response.ClearContent();

  return new HttpWebResponse(StatusCode.UnAuthorized){
             Content = new StringContent(url);
    }
```

But this seems terrible and counter to webapi "feel". Plus I'm tied to the controller in doing this. I can't get the wrapper in a MessageHandler for example.

What I'd like to do is monitor the response for a given route in a message handler or in an AuthorizationFilterAttribute, if its a 302, I want to read it's headers, take what I want, wipe it and replace it with my own "fresh" response as a 401. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to write your own ActionFilter and override its **OnActionExecuted** method where you can access **HttpActionExecutedContext**. From there, you can check response code, for example, and overwrite response with whatever you want.

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute.onactionexecuted%28v=vs.118%29.aspx#M:System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecuted%28System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpActionExecutedContext%29